# Printing output of multiple html files in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to print the text multiple files in html. I succeeded in printing the single file. But I am unable to print the text output of a multiple files. Can you please help me in correcting the code?`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
<h1> Testing programs </h1>

<input type="file" id="fileinput" multiple />
<pre id="file-content"></pre>
<h3>Contents of the file:</h3>
<script type="text/javascript">

  function readMultipleFiles(evt) {
    //Retrieve all the files from the FileList object
    var files = evt.target.files; 

    if (!files) {
        for (var i=0, f; f=files[i]; i++) {
              var r = new FileReader();
            r.onload = (function(f) {
                return function(e) {
                    var contents = e.target.result;
                    displayContents(contents);
                };
            });

            r.readAsText(f);
        }   
    } else {
          alert("Failed to load files"); 
    }
    function displayContents(contents) {
  var element = document.getElementById('file-content');
  element.innerHTML = contents;
  }

   document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readMultipleFiles, false)
</script>
</body>
</html>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `closure` in provided snippet. As suggested by *gurvinder*, use `innerHTML +=`

`if` condition should be like `if (files)` as it will be true if length of files is greater than `0`

Try this:

```js
function readMultipleFiles(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files;
  if (files) {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var r = new FileReader();
      r.onload = function(e) {
        var contents = e.target.result;
        displayContents(contents);
      };
      r.readAsText(files[i]);
    }
  } else {
    alert("Failed to load files");
  }
}

function displayContents(contents) {
  var element = document.getElementById('file-content');
  element.innerHTML += contents;
}

document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readMultipleFiles, false);
```

```html
<h1> Testing programs </h1>
<input type="file" id="fileinput" multiple />
<pre id="file-content"></pre>
<h3>Contents of the file:</h3>
```

Also refer this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/2cwr4c00/

Comment: Happy to help! Kindly [accept and up-vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) the best solution which has solved the purpose :) __Happy coding!__

Answer (score 1):

just replace the `displayContents` method as

```
function displayContents(contents) {
  var element = document.getElementById('file-content');
  element.innerHTML += contents; //observe + before =
}
```

since it needs to append the files rather than replace the last one

Comment: Still same problem. It just shows number of files uploaded

Comment: can you put a console.log or alert before calling displayContents method to check if the right value has been passed?